# Trying to INstall PHP on windows 7 ultimate with IIS6

Tags: php, iis, windows-7, iis-6

I am trying to install php on my windows 7 machine. I have installed IIS 6.x and I have also installed php.
I used this tutorial http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2006/09/19/How-to-install-PHP-on-IIS7-_2800_RC1_2900_.aspx 
The only thing I didnt understand is this part: 4) Install IIS7, making sure you install the ISAPI Extension component (for PHP-ISAPI - which is what I use) or the CGI component (if you prefer CGI) during IIS installation (ISAPI and CGI are *not* installed by default)

Now when i go to localhost I get an error.

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
4:         <handlers>
5:             <add name="PHP" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\web\php5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" />
6:         </handlers>
```

Also php pages do not work in IE, please help

Comment: You cannot install IIS6 on Windows 7.  Not possible.  You may have installed IIS, but it's IIS7.5, not IIS6.   For more info: http://www.iis.net/

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the simplest way to get PHP up and running is using Microsoft's Web Platform Installer which will setup everything for you, not only PHP, but also IIS, URL Rewrite, WinCache and FastCGI, all with one click.
So go to:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're using FastCgiModule but you've linked to the step-by-step version that uses ISAPI.
There's a link to the fastcgi version in that document: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-7/
And it also includes a section how to enable FastCGI support on IIS7.